# Cookie and session issues in php / mysql / wamp

Tags: php, session, cookies

I use wamp to develop on a windows 7 machine. For this app I have an admin area which tracks the admin username and encrypted password with $_SESSION and a cookie which keeps track of the randomly generated encryption key for the password.

I set the cookie like:

```
setcookie('key', $key, time()+7200, 'admin/');
```

The admin user verification is run on every admin page after the admin user has entered username and password details to login.

The directory structure of the site and the admin is:

```
localhost/mysite/
locahost/mysite/admin/
```

A session runs in the admin section, and a session also runs in the user interface of the front-end to keep track of chosen criteria for searches.

When I run long database queries in the admin area ie. multiple updates and inserts where each iteration requires a connection to an external API, I am unable to load the front-end user interface in the same browser ie. firefox until after the admin operation has completed. If I use a different browser ie. chrome , I am able to load the front-end of the site while running admin mysql functions with no problems.

I'd like to view the site while these operations are running, and use the same browser. It's a small problem, but I'd like to know how to get around it because I want to learn. I mean I could just tell myself that it doesn't matter because the site works fine when I open another browser, and the final user isn't going to be running admin operations while viewing the site anyway, so from that perspective it doesn't matter, but I am curious.

What is going on with the sessions and cookies that stops me from viewing the site whilst the admin operations are running? Is my question even a good one? Part of me thinks that it's a silly question because ultimately the site works perfectly well in a separate browser. Anyway, thank you for looking!

Comment: Actually it would be nice, if you can post a part of your script. We cannot help you unless the code is provided. Thanks in advance.

Comment: More code, less text :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your session is being locked. On the page that takes a long time to run add this at the top: `session_write_close();` that should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, this is a quick and simple answer. I appreciate it.